# Can't see images/photos thumbernails in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management

I'm new to ubuntu.  I've install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS by default installation.

I can't see images or photos thumbnails.

I've followed recommendations

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y ffmpegthumbnailer
```

But keep saying it can't find the package

```
sudo apt-get install -y ffmpegthumbnailer
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete ffmpegthumbnailer
```

I've also tried to fix any missing updates or broken dependencies

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f
```

Nothing improved, keep saying it can't find the `ffmpegthumbnailer` packet

I also tried to a recommendation from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKL9XBqe9Fg using Kali. Not successful either.

Thank you very much for your help, 
Monica

Comment: enable repo universe. https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: You don't need to install any package to see thumbnails. Where can't you see thumbnails? In the file browser? Usually its turned on by default, but you can see the settings in the Preferences -> Preview.

Comment: Have you tried right click on the picture that you want to see>properties>open with:>customize>accesories>Image viewer?

Comment: Thank you, with the viewer I can open it.

Comment: I've set Preferences->Search and Previsualization->Miniatures (thumbnails)->show miniatures "all files" but still does not change display mode to see thumbnails

Comment: Solved! Thanks. My ignorance. It was a matter of selecting the display in Nautilus navigation folder: instead of list of files, select icons